# When I sharpen edges, why do I get random spikes?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices, edges, topology

[image: This is my topology]

[image: This is my render]

Could someone please teach me how to get rid of these sharp spikes? It's really annoying and I'm not really sure how to go forward after this. Also, this only happens when I edge sharp. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your .blend file so we can investigate it. Personally, I've never seen that problem before. Maybe check your normals...

Answer (score 0):

welcome to BSE, you need to work more in the topology, that spike is an "ngon" that got triangulated by the sub-div modifier, for working with surf you need to have a decent quad topology to generate the shape you want.... you small objects seems not merged to that ngon, keep those separated like that...